# Velocity Template Foreach Character in String

Tags: arrays, string, foreach, velocity

I am using a velocity template to generate a report.  I do not have access to the Java code behind it only what is exposed to the template.  I have a string that I am trying to create an array from.  For example I would like to break "L-87623" into "L", "-", "8" etc.  Is there a way to do this using VTL?

Comment: You may possibly try using the String.split()

Answer (score 0):

It's not velocity but you may look into this example:

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        for(String s : "hello".split("(?<=\\G.)"))
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```